# How to paste picture into notes?

Tags: macbook-pro

I used to be able to paste pictures into the notes app on my personal macbook (I don't have it anymore). I've been trying to do this on my work macbook, and it doesn't seem to work. I'm running macOS v. 12.6 on a late 2021 macbook pro. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to do this? Are you copying the image itself from an open graphics app, or just copying the actual file from the desktop? If from an app, which app? Photoshop specifically needs to be told to export clipboard, as it can otherwise make clipboard sizes that are detrimental to the computer's performance. e.g., Test Note with 2 examples… one from a desktop file, one from Photoshop, selected area - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M4WE.png

Comment: @Tetsujin so actually, my use case is usually pasting a screenshot that I have in my clip board. that worked on my other macbook. I also just tried dragging a png file into notes (this also worked on my old macbook), and it said "Exchange accounts do not support attachments"

Comment: You just answered your own question. You have MS Exchange syncing the Apple Notes.app. You can likely turn off that function of Exchange on your Mac, assuming that is an option for you.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use anything Microsoft, so I've no idea how well it might integrate with Apple products.